# Xamarin form application crashing at SerializeObject not producing error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, json.net

I have a class which has a many to many relationship with student. Please bare in mind this is a xarmain forms application talking to the client using NewtownSoft

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BookingDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAbsent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public bool? HasCheckedIn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Student Class

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

I am adding that student to my api in the following way from the button click event.

```
private async void btnBookStudent_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 //if we want the booking to include our student we must add it to our colleciton.
 
    var test = Helpers.Dates.GetDateZeroTime(selectedBookingDate.Date).Add(timePicker.Time);
    var student = await api.GetStudentById(StudentId);
            

    var newBooking = new Booking
    {
            IsAbsent = false,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDeleted = false,
            Time = Helpers.Dates.
   GetDateZeroTime(selectedBookingDate.Date).  
   Add(timePicker.Time),
            DayOfWeek = DayNumber                 
                
    };
    newBooking.Students = new List<Student>();
    newBooking.Students.Add(student);
    await api.AddToBooking(newBooking);
    await DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName, "Booking Created For 
    Student", "OK");
 
}
```

However my client application is **crashing** out and not producing an **error**.

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> AddToBooking(Booking booking)
{
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = new HttpStatusCode();

    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ReferenceLoopHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize};

   string json = 
   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(booking,Formatting.Indented, 
   serializerSettings);


    booking.CreatedBy = db.GetActiveUser();

    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json");
    //    AddAuthenicationHeader();
    // Do the actual request and await the response

    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(Constants.BaseUrl + Constants.ApiSegmant + Constants.AddBooking, httpContent);
    statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;

    return statusCode;

   }
```

As said before in my previous post its not giving me an error my Xamarin forms c# android application its just crashing at the JsonConvert line.

I have seen some articles suggesting turning off reference loop handling works but it doesn't in my case as I need to add the student at time of the booking.

How do I get more details error information on what is happening I tried adding.

On my booking class but it doesn't even get fired?. A try catch doesn't catch it either.

```
[OnError]
internal void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
{
      var test = errorContext.Error;
}
```

I even tried [JsonIgnore] but i dont want that as I want the students to be with the bookings.

Comment: Can you also please add the student class?

Comment: Done but like i said in previous post no error is being created i tried a try catch didnt catch anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a self-referencing loop, as both models reference each other and if Json.NET was to serialise the object, it'd be stuck between `Booking` and `Student`.

Try ignoring the bookings from being serialised in every student using **`[JsonIgnore]`**.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Am puzzeled how u have such a low rep over x years joined that was indeed the answer. Duplicate so accounts are forbidden in SO land just pointing it out

Comment: I've just started using StackOverflow for contributing since yesterday - I've been a lurker over the past 6 years haha ;)

Comment: @csharpdude77 I'm aware yes, this is my only account - glad that helped.

Comment: If only life was as simple as c# we be laughing